# Arabtex & elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle, arabtex

I am trying to make an article (elsarticle) uses English as main language and some Arabic words embedded using arabtex but this error is generated:

```
Missing } inserted. \end{abstract}
```

I wish some one know about it, and has a solution.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{lineno} 
\journal{Journal Name} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frontmatter} 
\title{Unncessarily Complicated Research Title}
 \author{John Smith} \address{California, United States}
 \begin{abstract} here some text \end{abstract} 
\begin{keyword} Science \sep Publication \sep Complicated \end{keyword} \end{frontmatter} 
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names} 
\bibliography{Biblio} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a small document that shows the error, as the question is now,  it could be for any reason, including as the error says, a missing `}`

Answer (score 4):

the class uses slightly unsuported low level tex methods to grab the abstract into a box, which don't work well with arabtex's redefinitions.

In fact it works to do the most obvious thing suggested by the error message, supply an extra `}`

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{lineno} 
\journal{Journal Name} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frontmatter} 
\title{Unncessarily Complicated Research Title}
 \author{John Smith} \address{California, United States}


\begin{abstract}here some text}\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword} Science \sep Publication \sep Complicated \end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter} 


\end{document}
```

The above generates no error with the follwing versions as listed at the end of the log

```
 *File List*
elsarticle.cls    2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pifont.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR) 
    upzd.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
    upsy.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
   gg201.spl
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
 arabtex.sty    2003/08/22  3.11 ArabTeX main module
 arabaux.sty    2003/05/21  3.11 auxiliary macros for ArabTeX
    acmd.sty    2003/08/20  3.11 Arabic command processing 
  afonts.sty    1995/11/16  3.04 define Naskh font 
 afonts2.sty    1998/10/19  3.10 define Naskh fonts for LaTeX2e
   ascan.sty    2003/08/22  3.11 standard ZDMG input encoding 
  aparse.sty    2003/05/26  3.11 get syllables 
  awrite.sty    2003/06/05  3.11 build output word 
xarbsymb.sty    1998/07/15  3.07 symbolic output encoding 
arabskel.sty    2000/06/04  3.10 character skeleton definitions 
xarbskel.sty    1999/07/17  3.09 character skeleton definitions 
  aboxes.sty    2003/05/28  3.11 build output boxes
arabtoks.sty    1999/07/17  3.09 ArabTeX CS token definitions 
arabchrs.sty    1998/07/11  3.07 letter token definitions 
   aligs.sty    2003/05/26  3.11 compute ligatures
 aoutput.sty    2000/06/04  3.10 build output lines
  abidir.sty    2003/08/22  3.11 bidirectional linebreaking
  atrans.sty    2003/06/14  3.11 generate the transliteration 
  alatex.sty    2003/05/04  3.11 ArabTeX extensions for LaTeX 
   afoot.sty    2003/05/12  3.11 ArabTeX footnotes
   abjad.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 abjad numerals 
  apatch.sty    2006/07/02  3.11s last minute patches 
  alists.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 inverted list macros
   asect.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 section macros for Arabic
   atabg.sty    1997/01/21  3.05 LaTeX tabbing macros for Arabic
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  apatch.sty    2006/07/02  3.11s last minute patches 
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

Comment: I did try adding } but it did not work

Comment: @FaouziZaiz the above document runs without error.

Comment: I am using miktex 2.9 and texstudio, perhaps in different distribution and environment.

Comment: @FaouziZaiz add \listfiles to the document and it will list all used package version numbers. what error do you get from the document in this answer?

Comment: actully i did try even texlive distribution but the same error is generated

Comment: @FaouziZaiz the class already makes a file list, I added it to my answer. Compare with yours, some class or package must be a different version.

Comment: I add it to the preamble of the document, but I still get the same error

Comment: texstudio doesn't show any list of this type where can I find this list, in a separate file or what.

Answer (score 2):

this error happens with acm template as well.

Here is an answer to your question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299880/34604

The idea is to add this after loading arabtex package:

> \def\endabstract{\egroup}