# \end{abstract} conflicts with arabtext package

Tags: abstract, elsarticle, arabtex

I am using elsarticle

Everything was find before I used \usepackage{arabtext}.

When I compiled to PDF, I got the following error message.

[image]

And if I type "s", everything became fine again but I don't want to type an "s" every time I compile PDF preview.

Please anyone advise.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, authoryear]{elsarticle}    % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}          % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                            % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{arabtex}
%SetFonts

%SetFonts


\title{Translating from English to Bahasa Indonesia: Which procedures should be taught to EFL students preparing to be a translator?}
\author[mkl]{Mohammad Kholid}

\author[fai]{Faisal Mustafa\corref{cor1}}
\ead{faisal.mustafa@unsyiah.ac.id}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[mkl]{Syiah Kuala University, Banda Aceh, Indonesia}
\address[fai]{Syiah Kuala University, Banda Aceh, Indonesia}
\date{}                         % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
%\section{}
%\subsection{}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}

 Abstract content is here.

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
 translation procedures \sep English to Bahasa Indonesia \sep teaching translation
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: @FaisalMustafa, if it is really very simple code,, please copy it into your question. Many of people here (including me) is not willing to do this instead of you.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I have edited the question. Thank you very much for your very kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arabtex` package (precisely, `asect.sty`) does a redefinition of the `\endabstract` command, assuming it should be the same as in the standard classe `article`.

You can easily restore the definition of `elsarticle` by adding

```
\def\endabstract{\egroup}
```

after loading `arabtex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, authoryear]{elsarticle}    % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}          % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                            % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{arabtex}

% fix the redefinition of \endabstract
\def\endabstract{\egroup}
%SetFonts

%SetFonts


\title{Translating from English to Bahasa Indonesia: Which procedures should be taught to EFL students preparing to be a translator?}
\author[mkl]{Mohammad Kholid}

\author[fai]{Faisal Mustafa\corref{cor1}}
\ead{faisal.mustafa@unsyiah.ac.id}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[mkl]{Syiah Kuala University, Banda Aceh, Indonesia}
\address[fai]{Syiah Kuala University, Banda Aceh, Indonesia}
\date{}                         % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
%\section{}
%\subsection{}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}
 Abstract content is here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
 translation procedures \sep English to Bahasa Indonesia \sep teaching translation
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are a genius with a heart as white as snow @egreg..!