# Arabtex confilic with ACL2017

Tags: arabtex

I can't include arabtex because of these two errors:

```
\begin{list} on input line 64 ended by \end{abstract}. \end{abstract}
\begin{abstract} on input line 64 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

I have found similar problems related to arabtex, the solution is `\def\endabstract{\egroup}`
however it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is inspired by [\end{abstract} conflicts with arabtext package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299875/endabstract-conflicts-with-arabtext-package)

Add the following command,

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}%
         {\centerline{\large\bf Abstract}%
          \begin{list}{}%
             {\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.6cm}%
              \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.6cm}}%
           \item[]\ignorespaces}%
         {\unskip\end{list}}
```

after loading arabtex